# Extend search input in navbar header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In [this](http://www.bootply.com/129821) example the search input is very long until the end of page. I copied the html code but mine is short for some reason and couldnt really figure out the part that makes it long ? What's the trick ?

Code for my navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("KTEMB Veritabanı", "Index", "Members", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Üyeler", "Index", "Members")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Kayıtlı Personel", "Index", "Employees")</li>
            </ul>
            @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@
            <form class="navbar-form">
                <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What are searching for?">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a live demo of your code.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/HXbMDQLaie (container-fluid), and http://www.bootply.com/n4INnptaie (container) Seems to take up the full width here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you cited uses Bootstrap 3.1, using 3.3.x would explain why it doesn't work for you. Some of the other examples you'll come across use older versions of Bootstrap too - so they won't work with newer versions of BS.

This works a little better. Leaving the `.form-group` class at 100% width (which is default) is one of the things that causes a problem, so changing it to 95% or less works. Also, it appears to fail when using a float class, like `.navbar-right`, (which is why it was converted to `inline`) so watch out for those...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline; float:right; width:95%;">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:1%"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .form-group and .input-group, like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What are searching for?">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```